# Save svg to tempfile Python

Tags: python, django, svg, temporary-files

I am using a 3rd party python library that creates `.svg`'s (specifically for evolutionary trees) which has a `render` function for tree objects. What I want is the `svg` in string form that I can edit. Currently I save the `svg` and read the file as follows:

```
tree.render('location/filename.svg', other_args...)
f = open('location/filename.svg', "r")
svg_string = f.read()
f.close()
```

This works, but is it possible to use a tempfile instead? So far I have:

```
t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
t.name = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'tmp.svg')
tree.render(t.name, other_args...)
svg_string = t.read()
t.close()
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and/or how I could do this without creating a file (which I just have to delete later). The `svg_string` I go on to edit for use in a django application.

**EDIT:** Importantly, the render function can also be used to create other filetypes e.g. `.png` - so the `.svg` extension needs to be specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not define yourself the name of your temporary file. When you create it, the name will be randomly generated. You can use it directly.

```
t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tree.render(t.name, other_args...)
t.file.seek(0) #reset the file pointer to the beginning
svg_string = t.read()
t.close()
```

Comment: Nice answer but I realised I left out an important piece of info, check the edit. If I do it your way, the `t.read()` is just blank when I print it.

Comment: For the extension, you can use the `suffix` parameter. `t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".svg")`.
If `t.read()`is empty, did you try with the `t.file.seek(0)` line ?

Comment: This did the trick! The ``t.read()`` was only empty before because the render function didn't work without the extension. Works perfectly if you add the suffix in the way you describe.